# Animatedly reduce button size on press and regain it's size on release

Tags: android, android-animation, ontouchlistener, image-scaling

I want a to create a button that changes size (little bit smaller) when it's pressed, and after the button is released again the size should change back to normal size.I am using Scale xml to achieve this but it re-positioned itself even if i do not release button.

**button here i am referring to imageview.**

here is my source code :-

```
imgSpin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_spins);
    imgSpin.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    imgSpin.startAnimation(mAnimation);
                    spinslot();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    imgSpin.clearAnimation();
                    imgSpin.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

my scale Xml :-

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale=".8"
    android:fromYScale=".8"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" >

</scale>
```

my XML:-

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bootser" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/bet_bg"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight=".2"
                        android:src="@drawable/leftarrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Bet"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight=".2"
                        android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/container"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:text="winning"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_spins"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.9"
                    android:background="@drawable/spin" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

I tried with paramLayout but as i set the weights in XML so it do not give me the effect on animation.

i already use this approach :-

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = imgSpin.getLayoutParams();
                // Button new width
                params.width = params.width - (params.width *90/100);

                imgSpin.setLayoutParams(params);

                break;
```

**params.width always return me zero** so i tried to do this with weight , by using weight my view glitch on click ..i want it to be smooth so i am preferring scaling

Second approach :-

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imgSpin
                        .getLayoutParams();
                // Button new width
                params.weight = 1.7f;

                imgSpin.setLayoutParams(params);
                // imgSpin.startAnimation(mAnimation);
                // spinslot();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imgSpin
                        .getLayoutParams();
                // Button new width
                params2.weight = 1.9f;

                imgSpin.setLayoutParams(params2);
                // imgSpin.clearAnimation();
                imgSpin.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            }
            return true;
```

**it works but not smooth**

Please tell me how to do

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is what you want :-

```
imgSpin.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgSpin,
                            "scaleX", 0.8f);
                    ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgSpin,
                            "scaleY", 0.8f);
                    scaleDownX.setDuration(1000);
                    scaleDownY.setDuration(1000);

                    AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();
                    scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);

                    scaleDown.start();

                    spinslot();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    ObjectAnimator scaleDownX2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                            imgSpin, "scaleX", 1f);
                    ObjectAnimator scaleDownY2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                            imgSpin, "scaleY", 1f);
                    scaleDownX2.setDuration(1000);
                    scaleDownY2.setDuration(1000);

                    AnimatorSet scaleDown2 = new AnimatorSet();
                    scaleDown2.play(scaleDownX2).with(scaleDownY2);

                    scaleDown2.start();

                    imgSpin.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And just make this few changes in your xml :-

```html
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_spins"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.9"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/spin"
                    android:scaleX="1"
                    android:scaleY="1" />
```

make use of **scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY)**,it will keep the animated position and will not restore it back to original

Hope it solves your problem 
cheers

Answer (score 11):

1. Create two XMLs in /res/animator

   reduce_size.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set android:ordering="sequentially"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <set>
           <objectAnimator
               android:propertyName="scaleX"
               android:duration="300"
               android:valueTo="0.9f"
               android:valueType="floatType"/>
           <objectAnimator
               android:propertyName="scaleY"
               android:duration="300"
               android:valueTo="0.9f"
               android:valueType="floatType"/>
       </set>
   </set>
   ```

   regain_size.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set android:ordering="sequentially"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <set>
           <objectAnimator
               android:propertyName="scaleX"
               android:duration="1000"
               android:valueTo="1f"
               android:startOffset="300"
               android:valueType="floatType"/>
           <objectAnimator
               android:propertyName="scaleY"
               android:duration="1000"
               android:valueTo="1f"
               android:startOffset="300"
               android:valueType="floatType"/>
       </set>
   </set>
   ```
2. Usage

   On `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

   ```
   AnimatorSet reducer = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(mContext,R.animator.squeeze_in);
   reducer.setTarget(view);
   reducer.start();
   ```

   On `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

   ```
   AnimatorSet regainer = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(mContext,R.animator.squeeze_out);
   regainer.setTarget(view);
   regainer.start();
   ```

Answer (score 8):

Since API 21 (Lollipop) an xml-only solution is available based on the [stateListAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator) attribute. Here's an example of a layout which scale to 0.9 of its original size when it's pressed:

```xml
<!-- res/layout/my_layout.xml -->

<LinearLayout ...
  android:stateListAnimator="@animator/zoom_out_animator">...</layout>
```

```xml
<!-- res/animator/zoom_out_animator -->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <set>
      <objectAnimator
          android:propertyName="scaleX"
          android:valueTo="1.0"
          android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
          android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
      <objectAnimator
          android:propertyName="scaleY"
          android:valueTo="1.0"
          android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
          android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
    </set>
  </item>
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
      <objectAnimator
          android:propertyName="scaleX"
          android:valueTo="0.9"
          android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
          android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
      <objectAnimator
          android:propertyName="scaleY"
          android:valueTo="0.9"
          android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
          android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
    </set>
  </item>
</selector>
```

You can also find an example in the official material sample app [Owl](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples/tree/develop/Owl). Take a look at [onboarding_topic_item.xml](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples/blob/develop/Owl/app/src/main/res/layout/onboarding_topic_item.xml).

A few similar questions:

- [To increase a button's size when it is pressed in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3778401/4858777)
- [Android scale button on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38474593/4858777)

Comment: FYI, one problem with this solution is the order within the set. The pressed state needs to be listed BEFORE the default item. If it's not in the right order the animation will not work

Answer (score 2):

You can do this programmatically as follows on the touchlistener

```
new View.OnTouchListener() {
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      // scale your value
      float reducedvalue = (float)0.7;
      v.setScaleX(reducedvalue);
      v.setScaleY(reducedvalue);
    }
    else if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      v.setScaleX(1);
      v.setScaleY(1);
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple but you have to know how the Android API handles the call of each listener.

Here is the trick:

1- **onTouch** method in ***TouchListener*** will be called first. 
1.1- If **onTouch** method returns true, so **onLongClick**(in *LongClickListener*) or **onClick**(in *ClickListener*) will be ignored(both will not be called any more). 
2- If **onTouch** method returns false, then check if **onLongClick** returns true so **onClick** will not be called but if it returns false so **onClick** will be called as well.

Here is an example:

```
targetButton.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
        targetButton.animate().scaleX(1.2f).scaleY(1.2f).setDuration(0);
        Log.d("Button", "onLong: ");
        return true;
    });
    targetButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Log.d("Button", "onClick: ");
    });
    targetButton.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        Log.d("Button", "onTouch: ");
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            recordButton.animate().scaleX(1.0f).scaleY(1.0f).setDuration(0);
        } 
          // if you want to make it pretty increase the size when click also
          /* else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            targetButton.animate().scaleX(1.2f).scaleY(1.2f).setDuration(0);
            } */
        return false;
    });
```

In this example I am trying to increase the size of the button if I detect a long press, otherwise do something into **onClick** method, and if the user release the button I reduce the size again.

If you want the **onClick** called every time the **onLongClick** called just make the **onLongClick** returns false;

Answer (score 1):

You can add fillafter property: android:fillAfter="true"

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale=".8"
    android:fromYScale=".8"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" >
</scale>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/iv_spins"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1.9"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:background="@drawable/spin"
  android:scaleX="1"
  android:scaleY="1" 
/>
```

Comment: It's better to add explanation. What's your code/post intended to do. And don't use HTML code snippets for Android XML layout codes.

Comment: @Shashanth I removed the snippet and set it to a code block, still it needs an edit from rohit Shewale for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Solution**

1. Create extension function:

   ```
   fun View.addElasticTouchEffect() {
       this.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
           when (motionEvent.action) {
               MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                   this.animate().scaleX(0.96f).scaleY(0.96f).setDuration(100).start()
               }
               MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
               MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                   this.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(100).start()
                   if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                       this.performClick()
                   }
               }
           }
           return@setOnTouchListener true
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call created function in view:

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
       private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
           binding.ivAddress.addElasticTouchEffect()
           binding.ivAddress.setOnClickListener {
               // on click
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
<!--res/animator/scale_pressed.xml-->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
    </set>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="0.90"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="0.90"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
    </set>
</item>
</selector>
```

Basically it's the same as in [Valeriy Katkov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64911493/20918335), but I added `android:state_pressed="false"` without which it didn't work in my case.

And you can use it like that:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/scale_pressed"/>
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: GIF]